# I can't make ffmpeg work (error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.)

Tags: debian, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg this way:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

My distribution is:

```
Linux debian3 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The issue is, when I want to run `ffplay file.pcm` I end with the error message:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Could not initialize SDL - No available video device
(Did you set the DISPLAY variable?)
```

I tried with different audio files (mp3, wav), the output is always the same.

Comment: try `-vo null`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov. `Failed to set value 'null' for option 'vo': Option not found`. `-vn` also failed.

Comment: Are you using `ffmpeg` or `ffplay` or something else? What exactly are you doing? The ffmpeg package contains utilities and libraries.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, sorry and thanks. I updated my question.

Comment: `ffplay -vn file` should work. Does it fail with the same message? I'd compile ffmpeg from sources then. Looks like debian package is broken.